# Exsport function with Api call then import it on another page and wait for data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm new to all this `export`, `import`, `async` so please bare with me.

I have one file where I make API call and export that function so it can be used across other pages.

Of course on other page when function is invoked data payload is not yet there so i get undefind. So i tried to implement `async` (first time).
Please correct me if this is even possible or I I need some other method.

app.js:

```
  export function inboxMeniIkona () {

    //let req = xxxx
    fetch(req)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      } else {
        throw new Error('NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR')
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        return data // data here is allright
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('FETCH ERROR:', error))
  }
```

And then I tried on other page:

```
import { inboxMeniIkona } from '~/app'

      async function asyncCall() {
        console.log('calling');
        const result = await inboxMeniIkona();
        console.log(result);
        // expected output: "resolved"
      }
      
      asyncCall();
```

I'm still getting

```
CONSOLE LOG: calling
CONSOLE LOG: undefined
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add async in your functions and await in your fecth and return it like this.

```
export async function inboxMeniIkona () {

  //let req = xxxx
 return await fetch(req)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    } else {
      throw new Error('NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR')
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
      return data // data here is allright
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('FETCH ERROR:', error))
}
```

Comment: If that is only change I needed to make in my code, it does not work.

Comment: This way im not getting `console.log(result);` at all. Just `calling`.  I tired to remove `return new Promise(resolve => {` inside  `.then(data => {` but then is also `undefined`

Comment: why are you using this promise? why not just to return data? I just fixed your async and awaits commands.

Comment: Because that was my attempt, also I just said I removed it and just returned data, also undefined

Comment: Sorry man, you need to return it as i put in my answer, this is because you are getting underfined, because your not returning nothing, nonetheless you don't need this promise, at least I guess.

Comment: Works like this, with just return of data, thanks a lot!